# Firebase JSON to CSV conversion

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I convert an exported JSON firebase realtime database file to a viewable excel format.

Here is my JSON data for sample
Under no circumstances I could convert this JSON file to a viewable excel file. Please help me.
Are there any alternatives to this?
The best i know about this json file is that, this is a keyed JSON file that Google uses.

```js
{
  "2354" : {
    "15-07-2020_19:19" : {
      "actionTaken" : "Yes",
      "city" : "Varanasi",
      "divisionName" : "KANPUR",
      "duringVisitResolve" : "Yes",
      "errorCode" : "2",
      "finalRemarks" : "Pingtest Fail",
      "lat" : "",
      "lon" : "",
      "newMeterNumber" : "GP3620615",
      "newModuleNo" : "8288282",
      "newSealNumber" : "64949",
      "newSimNumber" : "89911500028407656055",
      "oldmeterNo" : "GP1232475",
      "oldmodulenumber" : "64949979794",
      "oldsealnumber" : "64949499",
      "oldsimnumber" : "89911554728407768686",
      "pageNumber" : "2",
      "ping" : "23",
      "recordDate" : "15-07-2020  19:19",
      "rssi" : "30",
      "sealingBookNumber" : "1"
    }
  },
  "741700122999" : {
    "15-07-2020_12:21" : {
      "actionTaken" : "Yes",
      "city" : "Varanasi",
      "currentAddress" : "2/436, Mandi Parishad Rd, Vibhav Khand, Gomti Nagar, Lucknow, Uttar Pradesh 226010, India",
      "divisionName" : "EDSD2 Varnasi",
      "duringVisitResolve" : "Yes",
      "errorCode" : "",
      "finalRemarks" : "Door Lock",
      "lat" : "LATITUDE:  26.86627563",
      "lon" : "LONGITUDE:  81.01962545",
      "newMeterNumber" : "gp7654321",
      "newModuleNo" : "",
      "newSealNumber" : "",
      "newSimNumber" : "98387928569838792856",
      "oldmeterNo" : "GP3624117",
      "oldmodulenumber" : "",
      "oldsealnumber" : "",
      "oldsimnumber" : "89911500028407706884",
      "pageNumber" : "",
      "ping" : "",
      "recordDate" : "15-07-2020  12:21",
      "rssi" : "",
      "sealingBookNumber" : ""
    },
    "15-07-2020_12:22" : {
      "actionTaken" : "Yes",
      "city" : "Varanasi",
      "currentAddress" : "2/436, Mandi Parishad Rd, Vibhav Khand, Gomti Nagar, Lucknow, Uttar Pradesh 226010, India",
      "divisionName" : "EDSD2 Varnasi",
      "duringVisitResolve" : "Yes",
      "errorCode" : "",
      "finalRemarks" : "Door Lock",
      "lat" : "LATITUDE:  26.86627563",
      "lon" : "LONGITUDE:  81.01962545",
      "newMeterNumber" : "gp7654321",
      "newModuleNo" : "",
      "newSealNumber" : "",
      "newSimNumber" : "98387928569838792856",
      "oldmeterNo" : "GP3624117",
      "oldmodulenumber" : "",
      "oldsealnumber" : "",
      "oldsimnumber" : "89911500028407706884",
      "pageNumber" : "",
      "ping" : "",
      "recordDate" : "15-07-2020  12:22",
      "rssi" : "",
      "sealingBookNumber" : ""
    },
    "15-07-2020_12:23" : {
      "actionTaken" : "Yes",
      "city" : "Varanasi",
      "currentAddress" : "2/436, Mandi Parishad Rd, Vibhav Khand, Gomti Nagar, Lucknow, Uttar Pradesh 226010, India",
      "divisionName" : "EDSD2 Varnasi",
      "duringVisitResolve" : "Yes",
      "errorCode" : "",
      "finalRemarks" : "Door Lock",
      "lat" : "LATITUDE:  26.86631405",
      "lon" : "LONGITUDE:  81.01964089",
      "newMeterNumber" : "gp7654321",
      "newModuleNo" : "",
      "newSealNumber" : "",
      "newSimNumber" : "98387928569838792856",
      "oldmeterNo" : "GP3624117",
      "oldmodulenumber" : "",
      "oldsealnumber" : "",
      "oldsimnumber" : "89911500028407706884",
      "pageNumber" : "",
      "ping" : "",
      "recordDate" : "15-07-2020  12:23",
      "rssi" : "",
      "sealingBookNumber" : ""
    },
    "15-07-2020_18:28" : {
      "actionTaken" : "Yes",
      "city" : "Varanasi",
      "currentAddress" : "2/436, Mandi Parishad Rd, Vibhav Khand, Gomti Nagar, Lucknow, Uttar Pradesh 226010, India",
      "divisionName" : "EDSD2 Varnasi",
      "duringVisitResolve" : "Yes",
      "errorCode" : "00",
      "finalRemarks" : "Meter Defective",
      "lat" : "LATITUDE:  26.86630446",
      "lon" : "LONGITUDE:  81.01963832",
      "newMeterNumber" : "gp1161819",
      "newModuleNo" : "7655",
      "newSealNumber" : "147",
      "newSimNumber" : "12345678901234567890",
      "oldmeterNo" : "GP3624117",
      "oldmodulenumber" : "123",
      "oldsealnumber" : "123",
      "oldsimnumber" : "89911500028407706884",
      "pageNumber" : "36",
      "ping" : "258",
      "recordDate" : "15-07-2020  18:28",
      "rssi" : "43",
      "sealingBookNumber" : "456"
    },
    "15-07-2020_18:29" : {
      "actionTaken" : "Yes",
      "city" : "Varanasi",
      "currentAddress" : "2/436, Mandi Parishad Rd, Vibhav Khand, Gomti Nagar, Lucknow, Uttar Pradesh 226010, India",
      "divisionName" : "EDSD2 Varnasi",
      "duringVisitResolve" : "Yes",
      "errorCode" : "00",
      "finalRemarks" : "Meter Defective",
      "lat" : "LATITUDE:  26.86630446",
      "lon" : "LONGITUDE:  81.01963832",
      "newMeterNumber" : "gp1161819",
      "newModuleNo" : "7655",
      "newSealNumber" : "147",
      "newSimNumber" : "12345678901234567890",
      "oldmeterNo" : "GP3624117",
      "oldmodulenumber" : "123",
      "oldsealnumber" : "123",
      "oldsimnumber" : "89911500028407706884",
      "pageNumber" : "36",
      "ping" : "258",
      "recordDate" : "15-07-2020  18:29",
      "rssi" : "43",
      "sealingBookNumber" : "456"
    }
  },
  "751601669466" : {
    "15-07-2020_02:19" : {
      "actionTaken" : "Yes",
      "city" : "Varanasi",
      "currentAddress" : "Near DVC More, Malancha, Kalitala, 713 103, Ichlabad, Bardhaman, West Bengal 713103, India",
      "divisionName" : "EDSD2 Varnasi",
      "duringVisitResolve" : "Yes",
      "errorCode" : "404",
      "finalRemarks" : "No Time To Solve The Problem",
      "lat" : "LATITUDE:  23.22290181",
      "lon" : "LONGITUDE:  87.88539515",
      "newMeterNumber" : "GP3620615",
      "newModuleNo" : "8188282",
      "newSealNumber" : "",
      "newSimNumber" : "89911500028407656055",
      "oldmeterNo" : "GP3625944",
      "oldmodulenumber" : "",
      "oldsealnumber" : "946646619194949",
      "oldsimnumber" : "89911500028407656055",
      "pageNumber" : "46",
      "ping" : "92",
      "recordDate" : "15-07-2020  02:19",
      "rssi" : "32",
      "sealingBookNumber" : "23"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of csv converter online. You can try https://json-csv.com/. Save the csv and open with Excel.